# Module not being found

Tags: python, installation, module, pip

I have tried to pip install two modules recently (ta and python-binance) however when I try to import both modules I get an error message(e.g ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ta').

I'm new to python and coding in general so it' probably a simple fix but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Any help??

Comment: Most likely there is path missing to the module. Try using sys.path.append(path) where path is path to your module location (usually where python is installed in site-packages)

Answer (score 0):

Do you run it with your system default python installation?
Maybe you run it with another version/installation/venv as the system default.

Because if you use pip install ... you install it for the python version that is in your environment variables

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you installed them correctly by

```sh
pip list
```

or

```sh
pip freeze
```